# How to use loop through for an object in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

the firstly I create a variable to store value from a loop after that variable get the value i want to using **For()** to loop through that object by using **javascript** function like **Object** and **Keys** but I can't see any thing in console.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: '<?PHP echo base_url('main/select_cat_by_group');?>',
            dataType: "Json",
            success: function (data) {
                fieldArray = {};
                $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                    fieldArray[val.gid] = val.gid;
                });
                for (var i = 0; i >= Object.keys(fieldArray).length; i++){
                        console.log(i);
                }
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

This is the Object result that I **console.log(fieldArray);**

[image]

Comment: Replace `fieldArray[val.gid] = val.gid;` with `fieldArray[val.gid] = val;` maybe?

Comment: Why you used >= condition for **For loop**

Comment: Use [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for iterate through object

Comment: You declare `i=0`, then try to execute the loop as long as `i` is greater than or equal `Object.keys(fieldArray).length` so the loop won't even start unless the object has no keys (in which case you'd have an infinite loop).

Comment: you can use for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use a `for..in` loop to iterate over objects:

```
for (var p in fieldArray) {
  console.log(p + '=>' + fieldArray[p]);
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3pgeh15m/)

Answer (score 0):

The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in arbitrary order. For each distinct property, statements can be executed

```
for (variable in object) {...
}
```

variable
A different property name is assigned to variable on each iteration.
object
Object whose enumerable properties are iterated.